# How to add new field into nested object in ElasticSeach?

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose, I have index with some predefined schema like

```html
     "mappings": {
          "transactions": {
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "properties": {
              
              "someDate": {
                "type": "date"
              },
              "nestedOjects": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                  "someField": {
                    "type": "text"
                  }
              }
            }
```

Now I need to update this mapping with adding new field into nested Object. I.e I want achieve something like this:

```html
     "mappings": {
          "transactions": {
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "properties": {
              
              "someDate": {
                "type": "date"
              },
              "nestedOjects": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                  "someField": {
                    "type": "text"
                  },
                  "newField": {
                    "type": "text"
                  }
              }
            }
```

Comment: do you want to update mapping or while adding data you want the mapping should get changed ?

Comment: Have you tried put mapping
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's consider you haven't created any index yet. Here first we will create index using your existing mapping as below (index name used `demo-index`):

**Create Index:**

```
PUT demo-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "properties": {
      "someDate": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "nestedOjects": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "someField": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To view the mapping of above created index you can hit the api: `GET demo-index/_mapping`

Update existing `demo-index` to add new field `newField` inside `nestedOjects`.

**Update Index Mapping:**

```
PUT demo-index/_mapping
{
  "dynamic": "strict",
  "properties": {
    "someDate": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "nestedOjects": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "someField": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "newField": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now if you again hit the api `GET demo-index/_mapping` you will get the updated mapping.

In case you need `transactions` as your head object & everything else inside it, then you can do the following (same while creating index):

```
PUT demo-index/_mapping
{
  "dynamic": "strict",
  "properties": {
    "transactions": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "someDate": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "nestedOjects": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "someField": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "newField": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

1. Create Index ref [API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html#mappings).
2. Update Mapping ref [API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#indices-put-mapping).

Answer (score 1):

You can update the nested object use the following update mapping API

```
PUT  /demo-index/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "nestedOjects": {
    "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "newField": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```